# Как отсортировать массив объектов по какому-то из ключей?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать фильтр массива объектов по условию ключа `read` от `false` к `true`?

```
array: [
    {sex: "male", name: "Alex Ivanov", message: "Lorem lorem inspur", time: "11:30", date:"11.12.2020", read: false},
    {sex: "female", name: "Olena", message: "Lorem lorem inspur", time: "11:10", date:"15.12.2020", read: false},
    {sex: "male", name: "Kirill", message: "Lorem lorem inspur", time: "11:20", date:"11.11.2020", read: true}
  ]
```

Comment: не совсем понятно что имеется в виду "от false к true", покажите как должен выглядить отфильтрованный массив

Comment: тоесть сначала обьекты с read: false за ними с read: true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Учитывая что `sort()` меняет исходный массив, то нужно создать копию исходного массива, можно таким образом: `[...array]`

```js
const array = [
    {sex: "male", name: "Kirill", message: "Lorem lorem inspur", time: "11:20", date:"11.11.2020", read: true},
    {sex: "male", name: "Alex Ivanov", message: "Lorem lorem inspur", time: "11:30", date:"11.12.2020", read: false},
    {sex: "female", name: "Olena", message: "Lorem lorem inspur", time: "11:10", date:"15.12.2020", read: false}
  ]

const result = [...array].sort((a,b) => a.read - b.read)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Обычно в базах и таблицах идет сортировка не только по одному ключу (полю)
а по каждому, но у каждой сортировки свой приоритет.

В данном случае приоритет по `read`

Тут два примера для наглядности я упростил объекты (даты нужно сортировать особо):

1. только по `read`
2. по `read` и `другим ключам`

Еще нужно помнить что функция сортировки работает с функцией сравнения возвращающей одно из 3х значений (об этом часто забывает что приводит к неправильному использованию, разные браузеры на эту забывчивость реагируют по-своему)

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a меньше b по некоторому критерию сортировки) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a больше b по некоторому критерию сортировки) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a должно быть равным b
  return 0;
}
```

```js
const arr = [
    
    {sex: "male", name: "B", read: false},
    {sex: "female", name: "B",  read: true},
    {sex: "female", name: "B",  read: false},
    {sex: "female", name: "A",  read: true},
    {sex: "male", name: "A", read: false},
    {sex: "male", name: "B", read: false},
    {sex: "female", name: "B",  read: true},
    {sex: "male", name: "A",  read: true},
    {sex: "female", name: "A",  read: false},
    {sex: "male", name: "B",  read: true}
]

let sorted;

sorted = arr.sort((a, b)  => a.read - b.read  );

console.log('----- неправильный вариант ------')

sorted.forEach(e => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e))  
})
   
console.log('\n----- правильный вариант ------')

/* не все сортировки правильны
   только по ключу 'read'
[
  {"sex":"male","name":"B","read":false}
  {"sex":"female","name":"B","read":false}
  {"sex":"male","name":"A","read":false}
  {"sex":"male","name":"B","read":false}
  {"sex":"female","name":"A","read":false}
  
  {"sex":"female","name":"B","read":true}
  {"sex":"female","name":"A","read":true}
  {"sex":"female","name":"B","read":true}
  {"sex":"male","name":"A","read":true}
  {"sex":"male","name":"B","read":true}
]

*/


sorted = arr.sort((a, b)  => { 
    let ta = 0, tb = 0; 
    
    const test = (a, b) => {
      if (a === b) return 0;
      if(typeof a == 'string') return (a < b) ? -1 : 1
      return Math.sign(a - b);  
    }

    ta += test(a.read, b.read) * 1000  // умножается на приоритет
    tb += test(b.read, a.read) * 1000  // больше число - больше приоритет
 
    ta += test(a.sex, b.sex)  * 100    // умножается на приоритет
    tb += test(b.sex, a.sex)  * 100    // больше число - больше приоритет
 
    ta += test(a.name, b.name)  * 10   // умножается на приоритет
    tb += test(b.name, a.name)  * 10   // больше число - больше приоритет

    return (ta >= tb ? 1 : -1 )
});

sorted.forEach(e => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e))  
})

/*
все сортировки правильны
првая выполнена по 'read'
вторая по sex (первое поле в `таблице``)
третья по имени (второе поле в `таблице``)

{"sex":"female","name":"A","read":false}
{"sex":"female","name":"B","read":false}

{"sex":"male","name":"A","read":false}
{"sex":"male","name":"B","read":false}
{"sex":"male","name":"B","read":false}

{"sex":"female","name":"A","read":true}
{"sex":"female","name":"B","read":true}
{"sex":"female","name":"B","read":true}

{"sex":"male","name":"A","read":true}
{"sex":"male","name":"B","read":true}

*/
```